# In Android, what's faster: Checking if a file exists on disk or looking up a flag from a SQLite DB?

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

I have many pictures in my app ( ~500 ) and more ( ~2000 ) on a server.

I would like to load the picture from disk if it exists, and will go to the web to download it if it's not on the disk.

Question: In order to very quickly check if a file is in fact on disk, I consider storing a flag in a simple SQLite table if the image is on disk. Would such a table with flags give me any performance gain, or is file system fileExists() just as fast?

( Yes, I know I could/should test it, but I would also be happy if someone has a quick answer ;-) )

FYI: I'm aware of Image loading libs such as Picasso, Glide, Fresco, etc but would still like to know which is faster, SQlite access for file system.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this not an eligible question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite databases are files. There should be less disk I/O in checking for file existence than in executing a SQL query.

Even faster is RAM. If you intend to do this check a lot, you might consider maintaining an in-memory cache of what files are on disk (e.g., a `HashSet<String>`) and checking against that.

Comment: Was wondering if there's any magic that SQLite does, maybe keeping the table open etc..

Comment: @treesAreEverywhere: If you don't close the database, the file may be open. However, AFAIK there is not much caching going on in the SQLite layer itself. If there were, then possibly if you have done similar queries before, the results would be faster. And that'd still be slower than maintaining your own bespoke cache, optimized for your situation.

Comment: Yes, the in memory cache is a great idea! Thanks for the thorough answers as always!